# asp.net doing a ToString on StackOverflow.Models.User+TopTagPercentile

Tags: bug, status-completed, developer-story

Not too sure how I got it into this state. Was editing my job details (selecting the proper company with image etc.) and noticed the below.

Refreshing doesn't fix it.

[image]

Comment: The devs are on it.

Comment: Note: I managed to replicate this if you add StackExchange sites to your story.

Comment: Looks to be fixed now.

Comment: @bluefeet if it was fixed it was not, I came here to report it, still see the same

Comment: @abatishchev Do you have the link to your story?  I'm not seeing the issue.

Comment: @bluefeet was still an issue at the moment of writing the previous comment. now everything looks good. thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This obviously was a bit of a bug. Which will be fixed in the most recent build.